# Pretty formatted json response with WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I'm using WCF RESTfull service which responds in JSON format, but by default WCF service sends not pretty formatted JSON messages (i mean json object without tabulation).

By default WCF sends JSON like that:

```
{"ResponseBody":{"Code":"0011","InvocationTime":278,"Message":""},"ResponseInformation":{"ServiceCode":0,"ServiceMessage":"Successfull","ServiceInvocationTime":0}}
```

But i need this:

```
{
"ResponseBody": {
    "Code": "0011",
    "InvocationTime": 278,
    "Message": ""
},
"ResponseInformation": {
    "ServiceCode": 0,
    "ServiceMessage": "Successfull",
    "ServiceInvocationTime": 0
}
```

Does anybody knows solution of this simple problem? Thanks!

Comment: Could you give us an example of the format which you would like to receive?

Comment: +1 for the code update :)

Comment: @AlexFilipovici, u are welcome :)

Comment: Just curious: why do you need it in "pretty" format? If this is being processed somewhere, the client shouldn't care what it looks like, and extra spaces just adds more bloat to the response. Are you trying to display the raw JSON in a screen somewhere?

Comment: @GarrettVlieger, i just debug my service and it is much more easy to review json response with tabulation. In production doesn't matter which formatting will be used.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx). Add a reference to the library (also available as a NuGet package) and add

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

to your class file. Then, do the following:

```
var json = "{\"ResponseBody\":{\"Code\":\"0011\",\"InvocationTime\":278,\"Message\":\"\"},\"ResponseInformation\":{\"ServiceCode\":0,\"ServiceMessage\":\"Successfull\",\"ServiceInvocationTime\":0}}";
var formattedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

normally wcf responds  in xml format .so if you specify that response in json, it will give the result in jason format.below example the request in xml format and response in json format.

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
       UriTemplate = "GetAllcustomer")]
   List< CustomerResponse> GetAllCustomerDetails();
```

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. My WCF service sends me that i really need. The question is how get json response in pretty format.

Comment: @Yaroslav, please update the question with a comparison between what you receive and what you expect to receive. _Pretty format_ could mean anything.

Comment: Yes, use Newtonsoft. You don't want to send 'pretty' JSON, send as few bytes as you can. If you want to see pretty JSON, paste it on this page and click 'validate'. http://jsonlint.com/